# Configure nemo on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, .desktop, nemo

I have made nemo default file browser in ubuntu 13.04 (unity).
Everything works fine. But I cannot find how to remove trash from desktop.
I tried gconf-editor but nemo is not there.

How can I remove trash from desktop ?

Probably something similar to:
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-trahs???? false ?

Answer (score 0):

Have nautilus not to draw desktop icons anymore:

> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false

Now, have nemo draw all desktop icons:

> gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true

Adjust which icons you want the desktop to show with dconf-editor

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my 13.10. Maybe it's the same fix for you.

You can fix it using this command in the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop trash-icon-visible false
```

Or manually in dconf Editor:

```
org > nemo > desktop
```

Untick `trash-icon-visible` for getting rid of the Trash icon. I've been looking for this myself and removed all these icons just now.